# Why is PostgreSQL 9.2 slower than 9.1 in my tests?

Tags: postgresql, benchmarking

I have upgraded from PostgreSQL 9.1.5 to 9.2.1:

```
"PostgreSQL 9.1.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4), 64-bit"
"PostgreSQL 9.2.1 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4), 64-bit"
```

It is on the same machine with default PostgreSQL configuration files (only port was changed).

For testing purpose I have simple table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_table_md_speed(id serial primary key, n integer);
```

Which I test using function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_DB_SPEED(cnt integer) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    time_start timestamp;
    time_stop timestamp;
    time_total interval;
BEGIN
    time_start := cast(timeofday() AS TIMESTAMP);
    FOR i IN 1..cnt LOOP
        INSERT INTO test_table_md_speed(n) VALUES (i);
    END LOOP;
    time_stop := cast(timeofday() AS TIMESTAMP);
    time_total := time_stop-time_start;

    RETURN extract (milliseconds from time_total);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I call:

```
SELECT test_db_speed(1000000);
```

I see strange results. For PostgreSQL 9.1.5 I get "8254.769", and for 9.2.1 I get: "9022.219". This means that new version is slower. I cannot find why.

Any ideas why those results differ?

Comment: I also tested it without `id SERIAL` column and results are very similar: 9.2 is slower than 9.1.

Comment: That is hardly a sensible performance test.

Comment: I know. That was part of larger test. It was slower in 9.2 and I cut it down to part that made difference.

Comment: "with default PostgreSQL configuration files" What's the point of these tests? A default configuration is next to useless for a production load, it doesn't mean anything that 9.1 might be faster in your test than 9.2.

Comment: Such results was first observed on production environment that differs from default. Then I cut test to the form presented and test it with default configuration on one of my test environments. It is easy test. I think something changed in PostgreSQL binaries, not configuration, but I cannot find that change. If something was changed in default configuration in 9.2 then of course my results will be wrong (affected by such change), but I cannot see such change either.

Comment: The whole point is: the default configuration is worthless. Using it for benchmarking purposes is clueless, IMHO. It could well be that 9.2 performs better if given more work_mem, or with a lower random_page_cost. It could be the other way around, too. Know what you measure, or don't measure at all. (in this example, you could be measuring disk I/O speed, for instance)

Comment: With the above test, I would at least expect a warning in the log about check_point segments being set too low. Did you check the log?

Comment: @wildplasser: I observe the same result on production environment that differs greatly from default configuration (higher work_mem, shared_memory,  etc). I also used `TEMP` table, so it should be in memory. Without `TEMP` results are worse, but 9.1 is better than 9.2.

Answer (score 3):

You say both are on the same machine.  Presumably the data files for the newer version were added later.  Later files tend to be added closer to the center of the platter, where access speeds are slower.

There is a good section on this in [Greg Smith's book on PostgreSQL performance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/books/), including ways to measure and graph the effect.  With clever use of the `dd` utility you might be able to do some ad hoc tests of the relative speed at each location, at least for reads.

The 9.2 release generally scales up to a large number of cores better than earlier versions, although in some of the benchmarks there was a very slight reduction in the performance of a single query running alone.  I didn't see any benchmarks showing an effect anywhere near this big, though; I would bet on it being the result of position on the drive -- with just goes to show how hard it can be to do good benchmarking.

---

**UPDATE**: A change made in 9.2.0 to improve performance for some queries made some other queries perform worse.  Eventually it was determined that this change should be reverted, which happened in version 9.2.3; so it is worth checking performance after upgrading to that maintenance release.  A proper fix, which has been confirmed to fix the problem the reverted patch fixed without causing a regression, will be included in 9.3.0.

Comment: I used TEMP table, so it should be in memory. Without TEMP results are worse, but 9.1 is better than 9.2. Test was also done on "clean" databases (initdb, and test in "postgres" database) installed one after the other.